# Fixed tictactoe error in notepad?

Tags: java, netbeans, notepad

> Hi i'm doing my assignment, i'm making a tic tac toe game. i'm using notepad for this purpose from my teacher instructions, i'm making 2 classes in a single notepad, a main class of TicTacToe name or 2nd GameBoard. everything is alright in netbeans but when i implemented in notepad and execute it through cmd then there is error
>
> **TicTacToe.java:16: error: class GameBoard is public, should be declared in a file named GameBoard.java**`

`

```
public class GameBoard {

private char[][] gameBoard; 

 public GameBoard() 
{ gameBoard= new char[3][3];
 for(int row=0; row<gameBoard.length; row++)
 {
java.util.Arrays.fill(gameBoard[row], ' ' );
}
    }
      public void displayBoard()
    {
for(int row=0; row<gameBoard.length; row++)
 {
for(int col=0; col<gameBoard.length ; col++)
{
System.out.print("\t" + gameBoard[row][col]);
 if(col==0 || col==1)
System.out.print("|");

  }
 System.out.print("\n---------------------------\n");
 }
  }

  }
```

This is my code

Comment: Notepad is not creating a .java file for you. You'll need to rename the .txt file's extension. When using an IDE like NetBeans, it does this for you.

Comment: but i'm using already named TicTacToe.java

Comment: read the answers -- namely, go see the Oracle documentation provided in my answer for direct guidance.

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one `public` class in a single Java file, and the name of the Java file has to match the name of the `public` class inside it. Some possible solutions:

**Option 1** - Pull the `GameBoard` class into a new file and name the file `GameBoard.java`. This means that you also need to [change the extension](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7) of the file. Make sure that the files are in the same folder, unless you want to add an `import` statement.

**Option 2** - Remove the modifier (`public`) of the `GameBoard` class (defaults to package-private)

**Option 3** - Nest the `GameBoard` class inside your TicTacToe class (you can still change/remove the modifier if you want to; `public` nested classes are usually not recommended)

Comment: if i changed the name then new error will be tictactoe should be declared etc

Comment: i'm using 2 classes in a single notepad , main class is TicTacToe and notepad also name is TicTacToe.java , and other class is GameBoard class, here is error exact           TicTacToe.java:16: error: class GameBoard is public, should be declared in a file named GameBoard.java`

Comment: private modifier not allowed here, and if i make a new file then how to access it from main file?

Comment: @user3668974 I updated my answer to make it more clear. Option 2 is the simplest but all 3 should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare two public classes within a single file (unless they are nested). Right now you have defined `TicTacToe` and `GameBoard` in the same .java file.

Read this tutorial on [class declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)

Comment: Yes you can, as long as only one of them is public. Try it.

Comment: if i nested them same error occor. @Zar can you tell me how to 2 access the new file GameBoard if i put it another file, from main file ?

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 public class allow per file (TicTacToe.java) so you need to rename it. You can make the other class with no access modifier :

```
public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameBoard board=new GameBoard();
        board.displayBoard();
    }
}
class GameBoard {
    private char[][] gameBoard;
    public GameBoard() {
        gameBoard = new char[3][3];
        for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard.length; row++) {
            java.util.Arrays.fill(gameBoard[row], ' ');
        }
    }
    public void displayBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < gameBoard.length; col++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + gameBoard[row][col]);
                if (col == 0 || col == 1)
                    System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.print("\n---------------------------\n");
        }
    }
}
```